# RuntimeError in Api: Circular dependency detected while autoloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I wanted to create a link (an api) for me to see the whole list of data collected, hence I created a new folder (api) under controllers, and named my file `records_controller.rb`

```
app/controllers/api/records_controller.rb

class API::RecordsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :set_headers

  def set_access
    @response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
  end

  def index
    @records = Record.all
    render json: @records, each_serializer: RecordSerializer
  end

#   before_action :require_user_id

#   def require_user_id
#     unless user_id
#       redirect_to :documents
#     end 
#   end
#   #user_id is correct = redirect to documents

  def create
    @records = Record.new(record_params)

    if @records.save
      render json: @records, serializer: RecordSerializer, status: 201
    else
      render json: @records.errors, status: 402
    end
  end


  private
  def record_params
    params.require(:record).permit(:record)
    end

    def set_headers
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET'
      headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    end
end
```

attached below is the `record.rb` file

```
app/models/record.rb
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :Number
end
```

And this is the `record_serializer.rb` file

```
class RecordSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :created_at, :Number
end
```

when i went to the website: `peoplecollection.herokuapp.com/api/records` it gave me `circular dependency detected while autoloading`

Please shed some light on this!

Answer (score 0):

Check your namespacing on the controller. You currently have `class API::RecordsController` and you probably should change it to: `class Api::RecordsController`